# Virtualbox use 1 VM to ping Google with HostOnly Net via another VM (jump VM)

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, kali-linux

Hello SuperUser Community!!

I'm so happy to write here, I'm stuck on a strange issue:

I've 2 VM on my VirtualBox lab

one VM has only the HostOnly Interface (eth0)
the other VM has the HostOnly Interface (eth0) and also a NAT Interface (eth1) with public internet access (ping 8.8.8.8 result OK)

So I just want do a very simple task: I wanna ping 8.8.8.8 via the first VM, so I added a route on this VM saying to use the HostOnly Interface in order to find 8.8.8.8

ip route add 8.8.8.8 dev eth0

I enabled the Forwarding Packets option on the second VM:

sudo echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

And I tried, with no success, I mean, on the second VM I receive the Ping request from the first VM but I don't obtain response.

Can you help me?

If can help, here the IPs assigned to the VMs:
-Net conf of VM 1: eth0: 192.168.56.104 (host only net)
-Net Conf of VM 2: eth0: 192.168.56.102 (host only net), eth1:10.0.2.9 (with public access).

Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Your 1st VM is connected to host only. There are only 2 machines in this network: host and VM. There's no 8.8.8.8.

Comment: actually from VM1 I can ping VM2
and if I ping 8.8.8.8 from VM1, VM2 receive the Ping (due to the static route added)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to MASQUERADE the packet received in the VM2.
In your case, I would try with:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: Thank you Giuseppe! It worked, you made my day. Bye!